# Error when attempting to cancel a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilocalnotification

I schedule a `UILocalNotification` from my `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:event.destinationTime]];

[notification setAlertBody:title];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
self.eventNotification = notification; // assigning to class property
```

And I try to cancel the notification when I delete the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:cell.eventNotification];
}
```

But when I run, I get the following error when deleting the cell:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

What is the problem? Or am I doing it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing in iOS8+ OR iOS7 and lower?

Comment: Have you asked permission to create local notification? If not then you have to first ask and if granted create local notification.

Comment: Please post the cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

First remove the item you are trying to delete from your data model

```
[_arrayOfData removeObjectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
```

Then delete the corresponding row from the table View

```
NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:cell.eventNotification];
```

}